# Minimizing redirects on external resources? http://tags.bluekai.com?

Tags: performance, .htaccess, redirect

Speed tests for my site tell me I need to minimize redirects on the following external resources. How can I find out where they're coming from / what they are?

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://sync.mathtag.com/sync/img?mt_exid=10002&redir=http%3A%2F%2Ftags.bluekai.com%2Fsite%2F4448%3Fid%3D%5BMM_UUID%5D
http://sync.mathtag.com/sync/img?mt_exid=10002&redir=http%3A%2F%2Ftags.bluekai.com%2Fsite%2F4448%3Fid%3D%5BMM_UUID%5D…
http://tags.bluekai.com/site/4448?id=f9555334-8a23-4a00-b276-17c871980eff&redir=http%3A%2F%2Fpixel.mathtag.com%2Feven…
http://pixel.mathtag.com/event/img?mm_bnc
http://ak1.abmr.net/is/pixel.mathtag.com?U=/event/img&V=3-tDz8DOXsfq2IXkSFMljlNxwPfU25KCavJ8SdLPhiHbvHfafqlYWD3Q%3d%3…
http://pixel.mathtag.com/event/img?01AD=320BjbpcbcCmrb9itCqDxTBz9jHryou5lsDILNAaE5bDY7c_27FsJAg&01RI=2BD46B098288529&…
http://cm.g.doubleclick.net/pixel?google_nid=mediamath&google_cm&google_hm=-VVTNIojSgCydhfIcZgO_w
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
https://ib.adnxs.com/getuid?https%3A%2F%2Fib.adnxs.com%2Fgetuid%3F%252F%252Fanalytics.stageaholic.com%252Fdough%252F1…
https://secure.adnxs.com/bounce?%2Fgetuid%3Fhttps%253A%252F%252Fib.adnxs.com%252Fgetuid%253F%25252F%25252Fanalytics.s…
https://ib.adnxs.com/getuid?%2F%2Fanalytics.stageaholic.com%2Fdough%2F1.0%2Fmixer.gif%3Fp_name%3DAN%26p_id%3D%24UID
https://analytics.stageaholic.com/dough/1.0/mixer.gif?p_name=AN&p_id=702885663948726277
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://cm.g.doubleclick.net/pixel?google_nid=bluekai&google_cm&google_sc&
http://cm.g.doubleclick.net/pixel?google_nid=bluekai&google_cm=&google_sc=&google_tc=
http://tags.bluekai.com/site/2981?id=&google_gid=CAESEPfUeVXdnKDiOJrsS_Hlpac&google_cver=1
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://i.w55c.net/ping_match.gif?st=BLUEKAI&rurl=http%3A%2F%2Ftags.bluekai.com%2Fsite%2F2964%3Fid%3D_wfivefivec_&
http://tags.bluekai.com/site/2964?id=8c23a317-f057-4905-8b79-0d0f36b3b198&
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://ib.adnxs.com/getuid?http://tags.bluekai.com/site/3085?id=&
http://tags.bluekai.com/site/3085?id=&
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://r.nexac.com/e/getdata.xgi?na_exid=D0JpqoCw99epQeHE&dt=br&pkey=ak930d7lx38dp&reppipe=%26phint%3D&repequal=%3D&v…
http://tags.bluekai.com/site/1407?limit=0&ret=pixel&phint=na_id=&phint=
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://tacoda.at.atwola.com/atx/sync/bk/bkid/2EkpqM8D99OPZpHE&
http://tags.bluekai.com/site/4470?id=19j92h31h55cb3
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://tags.bluekai.com/site/17736?ret=html&phint=category%3DCareer%20Business%20Industry&phint=category%3DScience%20…
http://tags.bluekai.com/site/17736?dt=0&r=1393951934&sig=1218064877&bkca=KJh+MA6nQA9xC7IBcAD6M9TKIkY/i98Nkt655cY5k56h…
```

How can I either get rid of or minimize redirects for external resources?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar issue. Are you using Shareaholic? Although I haven't found a solution, it sounds like this is related to their partner network settings on your account.

Comment: Check out http://support.shareaholic.com/hc/en-us/articles/201880333-How-do-I-turn-off-Third-Party-Data-Services-